# Problems with recieved data showing in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code snippet

```
`const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://c3interview.danshin.pro/graphql "
});
let Users =[];
let data = client
  .query({
    query: gql`
      {
        Users {
          ID Login AvatarURL
        }
      }
    `
  })
  .then(result => result);
 data.then(function(result) {
  result.data.Users.map(item =>  {
    return Users.push(item);
  })
  return Users;
});`
```

When I try `console.log(Users)` its console my users list, but when I am trying to `console.log(Users[0])` its console 'undefined'.
Please, tell me, what's wrong in this case?

Comment: `console.log(typeof users)` for more information

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to parse the response. Try with  JSON.parse(result.data.Users)

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://c3interview.danshin.pro/graphql "
});
let Users = [];
let data = client
  .query({
    query: gql`
      {
        Users {
          ID Login AvatarURL
        }
      }
    `
  })
  .then(result => result.data.Users).then((data) => {
   Users = data;
})
```